# Can we forcefully enable the 'Allow all cookies' of a google chrome from the javascript code

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cookies

Currently the application is running after I changed the chrome settings manually to 'Allow all cookies'. Can we forcefully enable the 'Allow all cookies' of a google chrome from the application JavaScript code.

Comment: Fortunately we can't, a code doing that is called virus.

Comment: You could enable it through Group Policy, but a better idea would be to fix your web-application to send cookies correctly rather than relying on insecure browser behaviour.

Comment: Thanks. We are using google sites and java script code is embedded in it. An iframe is used  to get the g suite authentication and the retrieved  email address is stored as a localstorage. This localstorage email is used in the other pages of the google sites. But unfortunately google chrome is blocking this.DOMException: Failed to read the 'localStorage' property from 'Window': Access is denied for this document. 
This is working only after the 'Allow all user' settings changed . Is there any other way to work this functionality.